Blog Posts Work in Preview, But Are Not Visible on the Live Page - READ MORE u003cspan aria-hidden=’true’u003e→u003c/spanu003e Error
Returning to a WordPress site that I have been away from for a while, I discovered that my Posts show up fine in Preview, but the actual page displays "READ MORE u003cspan aria-hidden=’true’u003e→u003c/spanu003e" in a link that circles back to the Blog page.
Googling the error shows a lot of sites with the same error, but not much help otherwise.
I disabled all my plugins and changed my themes, but I got the same result every time. I tried copying the whole Post and pasting it into a Page and it worked in both Preview and on the live page.
I'm assuming that the "aria-hidden='true'" is the source of my woe, but looking at the HTML in the blocks, doesn't show any aria elements.
Any direction would be greatly appreciated!
